# Nunit's Assert.Throws() does not show the tested method in Code Coverage

Tags: c#, nunit

```
var ex = Assert.Throws<SpecificException>(() => MethodUnderTest());
```

`MethodUnderTest()` will not show the SpecificException code path as being covered.

Is their a way to make this work?

Comment: Which code coverage tool you use? That should be marked as covered. Does the test passes?

Comment: Yes, the test passes.  CodeCoverage built in to VS2012.

Comment: Can you show `MethodUnderTest()` implementation?